Указание типа аргумента функции
Допустим что у нас есть два класса, A и B. При этом в классе A указывается тип аргумента B, а в классе B указывается тип аргумента A. То есть выходит примерно так:
class A:
    def __init__(self, b: B):
        self.b = b

class B:
    def __init__(self, a: A):
        self.a = a

Проблема в том, что класс B объявляется после объявления класса A, из-за чего интерпретатор Python'а его не видит. Есть ли решение помимо убирания указания типа аргумента?

Завернуть в кавычки

@andreymal, спасибо, помогло

Допустим, у вас получилось объявить классы. Перейдём к использованию: создаём первый экземпляр класса A. Для его создания нужен экземпляр класса B. Тогда создадим его. Но для него требуется экземпляр класса A, который пока создать не удалось - он был первый. Замкнутый круг. Объявить получилось, использовать не получится.

Можно не оборачивать в кавычки, специально для таких аннотаций есть from __future__ import annotations. Просто прописать перед остальными импортами и ничего не менять в коде.
